# Convert UUID to Hex representation using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a UUID some thing like 68753A44-4D6F-1226-9C60-0050E4C00067 which needs to be converted into 0xD7, 0x36, 0x95, 0x0A, 0x4D, 0x6E, 0x12, 0x26, 0x80, 0x3A, 0x00, 0x50, 0xE4, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x67.

Can some one please let me know how to do in cocoa or objective C

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Those two UUIDs don’t match. Also, what do you mean by converted? You need an array of bytes, or ASCII? What form is the UUID in? What are you feeding this to? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CFUUIDCreateFromString() to convert the string to a CFUUIDRef, then use CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes() to get at the raw bytes.

Comment: iOS6+ also has `NSUUID`, which is a little easier.

Comment: can you provide with example in objective c

Comment: Seriously?

CFUUIDRef ref = CFUUIDCreateFromString(NULL,(CFStringRef)@"xxxxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx");

CFUUIDBytes bytes =  CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(ref);
... do what you want by accessing bytes.byte0, bytes.byte1, etc.
CFRelease(ref);

Honestly, if you can't work this out from the API descriptions, you should not be attempting to deal with the raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code helped me to resolve the issue.

```
NSString *str3 = @"16433D43-C5DC-43A8-A35D-3F27ECCACFDC";
NSData* data = [str3 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString *hex = [NSMutableString string];
unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];
char temp[3];
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < [data length]; i++) {
    temp[0] = temp[1] = temp[2] = 0;
    (void)sprintf(temp, "%02x", bytes[i]);
    [hex appendString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: temp]];
}
NSLog(@"Hex %@",hex);
```

Output will be some thing like this : 33343445323944452D333946352D343941372D414543312D453539423130443444413836